# Unable to write left square bracket in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, brackets

Why can't I write a left square bracket in TexStudio?

Comment: This can happen, if you have in some window a remote session running. Go to the session and type alt+space in non full screen mode. Let the menu open, switch back.

Comment: I dont understand what session you are talking about. Please explain. Thank you for your answer btw

Comment: Do you have any programs opened beside TeX Studio?

Comment: What OS do you have? On what machine?

Comment: I am running Windows 10 21H2. I do have other programs open. Brave browser etc. HP Zbook G2

Comment: Reproduce the problem. As soon as it occurs, close one program after another. And check in between, if it is already working. Soon you will identify the culprit.

Comment: I closed all the programs and it still doesn't work. I can write it everywhere else.

Comment: Try typing ctrl+shift then try for the square bracket again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved the problem.

To write left square bracket I have to use Alt + Shift + F (AltGr + F) on my keyboard. This combination is used as a default shortcut for: `Idefix->Go to->Definition`.

The problem was solved by assigning a different shortcut for this command in `Options ->Configure TeXstudio-> Shortcuts etc`.

I can now write the left square bracket.